# Paypal: Mapping API credentials with sandbox credentials

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

The documentation for paypal adapative api requires the developer to send 6 headers amongst which there are:

```
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID : Sandbox-Caller-User-Id
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD : Sandbox-Caller-Password
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE : Sandbox-Caller-Security-Signature
```

The trouble is I don't know where to find the USERID, PASSWORD and SIGNATURE

In the below screenshot that I took from the Paypal Sandbox Business Account, there is no such thing as USERID, PASSWORD and SIGNATURE.  Instead I have Sandbox account, Endpoint, Client ID and Secret.

Screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6599473/Capture.PNG

So which is which?  What is the userid? What is the password? and what is the signature?

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot you've provided is for the REST API.  UN, PASS, and SIG are for the Classic API.

You can obtain those credentials [logging in here](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run) with your PayPal account.

You can [find more details here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/).